# How to prevent editing of TextBox before certain position?

Tags: string, vb6, textbox, keypress

How can a `TextBox` be prevented from being edited before a given position?

For example, if a `TextBox` contains the string:

> Example Text: The black cat.

How can I prevent the user from editing anything before `"The"`?

I can try to trap the `Backspace` key with the `KeyPress` event, but how can I use `MouseClick` to prevent the user from moving the cursor to a position before `"The"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a single-line `RichTextBox` and protect the prefix like this

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Const STR_PREFIX = "Example Text: "

    RichTextBox1.Text = STR_PREFIX & "The black cat."
    RichTextBox1.SelStart = 0
    RichTextBox1.SelLength = Len(STR_PREFIX)
    RichTextBox1.SelProtected = True
    RichTextBox1.SelLength = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Works well except for some copy/paste issues.

Comment: @Bob77: what are the copy/paste issues?

Comment: If you select all of the text, paste it back, an object package gets pasted back in there along with the unprotected text.

Comment: If protected text selected I can't copy to clipboard with `Ctrl+C` here, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextBox_Changed` Event and then check its `Text` property. If it does not start with "The" you put back "The black cat".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 2ways. 1) On the change event, test to see if "the" is still at the beginning, and if not, add it.  2) Put the "the" in a label before the text box. You can even format it so it looks like the same control to the user.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a static text item you have pre-defined then I would take this approach:

Have the default value of the texbox as "The black cat " so the user can immediately see it.

Then use the **OnGotFocus** event of the textbox to remove the first 14 characters (The black cat ) with a space at the end.  The user can then freely type what they want (this will preserve anything they have already typed if editing for a second or further time)

```
TextBox = Right(TextBox, Len(Textbox) - 14)
```

Then using the **OnLostFocus** event you can place the 14 characters back at the beginning of the textbox.

```
TextBox = "The black cat " & TextBox.Value
```

This method should avoid any complications from the user clicking the mouse anywhere in the field, you also don't need to track the physical data with the **Change** events.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- you want a static 'non-editable' string to be in the `TextBox` control
- you can click on this string, select it and it will look just like any other text in the text box, only difference is you will not be able to change it
- the `TextBox` name is `txt1`

> ```
> Dim str As String
> Dim oldStr As String
> Private Sub Form_Load()
>     str = "The"                     ' static string that you do not want to be edited
>     oldStr = str + " black cat"     ' default string to start with in the text box
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub txt1_Change()
>     If UCase(Left(txt1.Text, Len(str))) <> UCase(str) Then
>         ' the static string was edited, so we restore it to previously 'good' value
>         txt1.Text = oldStr
>     Else
>         ' string was changed, but the change is 'good'. Save the new value
>         oldStr = txt1.Text
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

This code will prevent the predefined string (`str`) from being edited in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

the following example doesn't accept keyboard input when you are before the marked start position, and when clicked inside the box before that position, it moves to the start position

these are 2 different answers upon unwanted actions .. you might want to use the same action in the _keypress and _click events

```
'1 form with
'    1 textbox : name=Text1
Option Explicit

Private mintStart As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Text1.Text = "Example text: The black cat"
  mintStart = Len("Example text: ")
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Text1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Click()
  With Text1
    If .SelStart < mintStart Then
      .SelStart = mintStart
    End If
  End With 'Text1
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  If Text1.SelStart < mintStart Then
    KeyAscii = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your textbox to locked, then try this.

```
Private Sub Text2_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   Dim TextMin As Integer
   TextMin = 3
   If Text2.SelStart > TextMin Then
      Text2.Locked = False
   ElseIf Text2.SelStart <= TextMin Then
      Text2.Locked = True
   End If
end sub
```